# How to Get Populate Comboboxes Values From Gridview in WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, combobox

I want to get grid view data in the `StudentRegistrationForm`. I have tried many times, but I am unable do this, and I don't understand. Can you tell me how I can get GridView values in my `StudentRegistrationForm`?

If I comment combo boxes code, then other values are put in `StudentRegistrationForm`, but I want to show all data in `StudentRegistrationForm`.

[image]

```cs
St_Registration obj = new St_Registration();
int St_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
obj.txt_name.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
obj.txt_fname.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
obj.txt_sur_name.Text =dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
obj.txt_email.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
obj.dob_date.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
obj.date_of_registration.Text=dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
obj.txt_address.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
obj.rbtn_male.Checked = true;
obj.rbtn_female.Checked = false;

if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString() == "Female")
{
    obj.rbtn_male.Checked = false;
    obj.rbtn_female.Checked = true;
}
obj.txt_contact.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
obj.cmb_country.Text=dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
obj.cmb_province.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
obj.cmb_city.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
obj.txt_pin.Text=dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[13].Value.ToString();
obj.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: The code looks like you're taking the items from the selected row in the grid and putting the data into the ST_Registration obj, but not into the controls on the form. Do you have a data source on the form that's connected to this obj or are you talking about the dialog launched by obj.ShowDialog() ?
I'm not sure where comboboxes comes in, I don't see any combobox related code here.

Comment: What happens when you click `Get Data` button? Can you share code of that? What should happen when you click on `Get Data` button? What do you mean by `I can't do this`?

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: After click the Get Data Data Button, then Data will save another form Show Data in GridView.

Comment: Basically, I have Applied Modifier Public After that I will use them with another form with the help of creating an object. I have mentioned above codes, you can see one form is a registration form, and the second form is a show data in grid view.  So, I have got data with St_Registration Form without combo boxes values. But, I want to get all values show on the st_registration form.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your setup. Which of your forms is your primary form? How do I get from one form to the other? Your code suggests DataGridView form opens your StudentRegistrationForm, but that seems weird because there are CRUD options on that form and you would only be able to do them by selecting an existing student.

Comment: I don't know why you are don't understand? but can you tell me How I can get Populate Combobox Data From DataGridview? 1) FormOne available complete bio-data. 2) Data Show Another Form GridView, How I can get data form second from grid view like textboxes, radio buttons, combo box. Please Tell me How I can do it, I have been waiting for 3 days. I have tried many times, but I can't do this.